# sed output in case of not match

Tags: bash

I want to extract some fields from a line, like:

```
echo "aaa,bbb-ccc,ddd" | sed 's/.*,\(.*\)-\(.*\),.*/\1 \2/'
```

It will output `"bbb ccc"` as i expect. But if the input line is not of the pattern,

```
echo "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" | sed 's/.*,\(.*\)-\(.*\),.*/\1 \2/'
```

It will output the whole line `"aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd"`. What i want is when not matched, output nothing. How can i do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/.*,\(.*\)-\(.*\),.*/\1 \2/p'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "aaa,bbb-ccc,ddd" | sed -n 's/.*,\(.*\)-\(.*\),.*/\1 \2/p'
bbb ccc
$ echo "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" | sed -n 's/.*,\(.*\)-\(.*\),.*/\1 \2/p'
$
```

`-n` disables printing of the pattern space by default.

`p` makes `sed` print when matched.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "a-b" | sed -n 's/-/#/p'
a#b

echo "a_b" | sed -n 's/-/#/p'
```

-n means 'no output' as default.
/p means print

Answer (score 1):

If that's the case, think of a simpler approach

```
echo "aaa,bbb-ccc,ddd" | awk -F"," '$2 ~ /-/{ print $2}'
```

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: It outputs "bbb-ccc" instead of "bbb ccc" (it properly rejects "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd", however).